# Eloquent Update with One-to-One relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am want to update my records in my database using **Eloquent model**. I am having an error in updating `user_profile` table that saying `where id is not null`.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Common\UserProfile');
    }
}
```

**UserProfile Model**

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$user->fill($data);
$user->save();
$user->profile->fill($data);
$user->profile->save();
```

**In MySQL query it looks like this:**

```
UPDATE users, user_profiles
SET users.name='Test Name',
user_profiles.email='test@gmail.com'
WHERE users.id=1
 AND user_profiles.user_id=1;
```

I know MySQL query but I'm new to `Eloquent` and I want to do it in `Eloquent model`. Maybe there are some in here that can provide an explanation on how the *magic* works in `Eloquent`.

Comment: Does your code work? If not - what exactly doesn't?

Comment: it doesn't work. it returns `update user_profile set name='some name' where id is null`. the error occur in `$user->profile->save();`

Comment: Show the code where you initialize `$user`. I guess the profile relation is not loaded.

Comment: I realize that there is no `id` column in my `user_profile` table instead `user_id`, so I think that is the main problem. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';` in your `UserProfile` model.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I get it, my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default eloquent assumes, that any model has an `id` column as primary key. If that is not the case, you need to "register" the primary key with

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

in the model class.